# Delay or bug in sending careers.so.com email verification messages?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

I registered for careers.stackoverflow.com today and everything is great except that I don't seem to get the verification email message. After waiting 30 minutes I have received nothing in my email account (hosted Google Apps email). I have checked the spam folder but can find no message.  I returned and re-clicked on the "verify your email" link and again nothing.  Interestingly I did receive, in a flash, the billing confirmation message at the same email address.

So, is there a deliberate delay?  An issue?  A bug?  Or maybe Google is blocking it?

Comment: Same here - no mail was received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep I confirmed that no mails were going out.

We were erroneously using our hosted gmail to send mails instead of our local SMTP server (this is really a local development mistake that got promoted to production, I am now calibrating my project blame-o-meter to *STUN*). I think we hit the gmail limit of 1500 emails per day.

I corrected that mistake, switched to our local SMTP server, and verified that mails are now going out. So you may want to click the "resend verification email" again...

Answer (score 0):

I got mine in less than 10 seconds.  I'm guessing something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Me too.  I'm still waiting, and it has been *tens of minutes* now.  Spam folders have nothing.  I use fastmail.fm

Something is all clogged up in that series of tubes.